# JSF2 + Eclipse + Glassfish strange output problem

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6

I try to make a simple JSF2 application in Eclipse indigo. 
I have a very simple ManagedBean (call HelloBean.java)

```
package server;



@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class HelloBean {

    private String name;

public HelloBean() {
}

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And this is my index.xhtml:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:head><title>JSF 2.0 Hello World</title></h:head>
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText value="#{helloBean.name}"></h:inputText>
            <h:commandButton value="Welcome me" action="welcome"></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
</html>
```

In eclipse I created an user library called JSF2.0 and added the jsf-api... and jsf-impl jars. In the projects setting I choosed JavaServer Faces.
When I publish this really dummy app, and check a browser I see a totally blank page.
Only the title is ok, but the rest of the content doesn't appears.

I checked the server log file, no warning no error, it looks ok.

What's the problem? Am I miss something important?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What are you importing or ManagedBean and RequestScoped.  Make sure they are in the JSF packaged and not the CDI.  Also map your faces servlet to .jsf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have the `Faces Servlet` in your `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then make sure that your URL contains `faces` prefix, like `http://localhost:8080/faces/index.xhtml`.

Comment: Uhh, my bad! I'm such a blind, thank you so much! It helps, everything's working fine.